# Is it OK to post a question from my account but asked by a friend?

Tags: discussion

A buddy of mine told me that he can't post on the StackO for some reason and he sent over a question to me. Is it all right to post it for him under my name? I checked that he isn't banned or anything and that the question is legit.

Or should I refrain from such?

Comment: If other users comment with questions can you answer them? If they aren't banned, why can't they post? Are you sure they're not being throttled (e.g. limits for questions per 24 hours)?

Comment: I.... I mean there is new issue... But i still wonder why. I dont really see why HE can't post it himself (especially if he isn't banned as you say). Why does he want you to post it and not him?

Comment: Note that if he was question banned, you wouldn't be able to tell other than by looking over his shoulder while he tried to post a question. These don't usually show up like manual suspensions do in the user profile.

Answer (score 16):

If your friend cannot post here, and you want to post their content, you should make *extra* sure that their content is not the reason they cannot post.

That said, there is nothing that says you cannot post questions from your friends. You may want to avoid voting on each others content though, as that is frowned upon.

Comment: I believe he's not able to login from the workplace for some reason. I can't see the point to block StackExchange at any office but who knows... He does something with the government and I wasn't allowed to take that assignment because I'm not a citizen, so maybe some weird security?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it all right to post it for him under my name?

Such kind of stuff is often identified as bogus and merely sock puppetry.

Make sure that the content to be posted is still on topic, and you would a 100% support it.

> Or should I refrain from such?

Otherwise do so.